# What is notified-SplashPage?

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-404

I'm seeing a lot of `notified-SplashPage` and  `verify-SplashPage` entries showing up in our apache error log

```
[Wed Jan 20 15:00:22 2010] [error] [client xxxxx] File does not exist: /home/site/htdocs/notified-SplashPage, referer: http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=xxxxx
[Wed Jan 20 15:00:22 2010] [error] [client xxxxx] File does not exist: /home/site/htdocs/verify-SplashPage, referer: http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=xxxxxx
```

There are others that come in a similar pattern (notified-Compliance etc) and always seem to be connected with google.

Anyone know what google is trying to find out? If it isn't google, does anyone know what they are meant to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.tobyandlauren.id.au/notified-and-verify-requests/) and [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/3859463.htm) - they seem plausible explanations to me. Basically these are requests to see if you're using a product called ProxySG and possibly exploit it